# Using Ajax to submit a form and returning a confirmation page

Tags: dxa, web8, c#, iis-and-asp.net, mvc

I am trying to submit a form through an ajax process :

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendEmail", "Form", new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "replace",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "Post",
        }))
        {
         // the form details
        }
```

the action for this form is defined in the Form controller as:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SendEmail(EnquiryFormViewModel model)
        {
           _sendForm.SendFormByEmail(model.FirstName, model.Surname, model.Email, model.NatureOfEnquiry,model.Message);
            return PartialView("EmailResult", model.FormMetaData);
        }
```

The route is defined in the global.asax as:

```
  //Form button
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "FormButton",
                url: "Form/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Form", action = "SendEmail" }
                ).DataTokens.Add("area", "Core");
```

The action is supposed to return a partial page that contains some information about the successful submission of the form and thanking the user. However, as soon as the button is clicked, I get a 404 error that Requested URL: /Form/SendEmail is not available. 
The action method is executed, but I can't get the page that I am supposed to get through the action. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this question specific to Tridion/DXA, or is it a general question about ASP.NET MVC. If it's the latter, stackoverflow is probably a better bet.

Comment: @DominicCronin the question is with in the context of Tridion/DXA. It would be very simple to do this in normal ASP.Net MVC. But, somehow in the DXA it is not working.